# Node JS Writing to a text file in ubuntu. Permission Denied

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fwrite

I am writing my logs to a text file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("server_logs.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

But I am getting this error.

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'server_logs.txt'

Comment: Try to change the permission using `chmod` command..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sudo chown` command to set the appropriate ownership/permissions to your `server_logs.txt`file, You can use the below command to acheive that.

```
sudo chown $USER server_logs.txt
```

Hope this helps!